# Adding a Maven dependency composed by several modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having problems to add a dependency to my project. It's a framework whose structure, once maven-installed, is composed by several modules, looking (simplified) like this:

- build-XXX (containing .pom)
- build-XXX-root (containing .pom)
- build-XXX-superpom (containing .pom)
- filters (containing .pom)

  - build-filters (containing .pom)
  - filter1 (containing .jar)
  - filter2 (containing .jar)

What I want is to add the whole framework as a dependency, to use any content of any of the jars. I thought that adding the superpom, the `build-xxx-root` or `build-xxx` will solve it, adding all the children modules automatically; but I didn't work.

The remote repository can be accessed [in this link (CloudBees)](http://repository-okapi.forge.cloudbees.com/release/); it's an open-source project, in case anyone wonders about the original file structure [it can be found here (Bitbucket)](https://bitbucket.org/okapiframework/okapi/src).

I have added the remote repository into the `pom.xml` in the following way:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>okapi-release</id>
      <name>Okapi Release</name>
      <url>http://repository-okapi.forge.cloudbees.com/release/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

And then I have tried with different dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.okapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-okapi-superpom</artifactId>
  <version>0.27</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.okapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-okapi</artifactId>
  <version>0.27</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But neither of them worked.

I'm not obtaining any error and inside of it, two dependencies are recognized, but I cannot import packages from the framework or use any of the classes.

[image: Dependencies that appear]

I'm familiar with basic Maven, but this structure composed by poms, child poms, and child jars, really confuses me; after several hours and random tries, I have decided to ask here... any suggestion?

Comment: You need to add the filter1 and filter2 modules explicitly. Adding the (super) POM doesn't include the modules defined within it.

Comment: Re _"confuses me"_ – see [POM Reference, POM Relationships](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships) (there are just three kinds of them) and [Maven: The Complete Reference , 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book//reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit).

Comment: Thank you both! So if I'm adding the modules explicitly, and they contain the needed dependencies information inherited from the parent POMs, I don't need to add the parent modules which just contain POMs as dependencies, right?

To follow with the example, I just have to add dependencies to filter1 and filter2; not to build-filters nor build-root.

Comment: @ÁlvaroReneses Correct.